# Multiple same Async Await function only Triggered the Last One

Tags: javascript, function, async-await

```js
const fun = (x) => {
  console.log(`Meth... ${x}`);
  setTimeout(() => {
    onReceive(`Fun Received: ${x}`);
  }, 100);
  return x;
}

const publish = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    window.onReceive = (token) => {
      resolve(token);
    }
  });
}

const Inst = () => {
  const getAs = async(x) => {
    console.log(`Getting As ----- ${x}`);

    const res = await publish(fun(x));

    console.log(`Res is '${res}' ---- ${x}`);
  }

  return {
    getAs,
  }
}

const inst = Object.freeze(Inst());

const a = async() => {
  await inst.getAs(1);
  await inst.getAs(2);
  await inst.getAs(3);
  await inst.getAs(4);
  await inst.getAs(5);
};
a();

const b = async() => {
  await inst.getAs(4);
  await inst.getAs(5);
  await inst.getAs(6);
  await inst.getAs(7);
};
b();
// Comment or remove `b()` to see the different result in Console
```

---

I got confused why the function only called the last `async await` **(`b()` from the example)**. Why inside of **`a()`** seems like didn't get called at all??

If I comment / remove **`b()`**, all inside of **`a()`** will get call.

Need helps / explanation to resolve such issue .

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question. Don't link to external code.

Comment: I copied your externally-hosted code into the question.  It is preferable to use the "snippet" tool here (the icon with `<>` on it) instead of external sites, as external links have a tendency to rot and make the question useless for future users.

Comment: @DanielBeck Please don't do this. I'll roll back. The author has to do this by themselves. [Copy large code block from external source to an answer to "secure" it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275485/copy-large-code-block-from-external-source-to-an-answer-to-secure-it)

Comment: Ah!  That'll teach me to try to be helpful :) (but seriously, though, thanks @jabaa, I wasn't aware of that; it makes sense)

Comment: @DanielBeck I was taught the same way. I copied the code from external source and another user rolled back my change and posted the link.

Comment: The system works :)

Comment: All the promises in `publish` are overwriting the previous value of `window.onReceive`. You have to add listeners instead of overwriting them.